# Gridview Update error

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am doing a small application in ASP.net(C#) with MS Access. I have a Gridview where I have a "Update" command. During run time I had put break point in RowUpdating() method. Everything works on well with no errors, the parameters are getting updated in the code behind. But in the output, gridview is not updating and also not in DB.

**HERE IS THE CODE:**

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) 
{    
    string ID = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text; 
    string CName= ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text; 
    string AName = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text; 
    string APhone = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;
    string AEmail = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Controls[0]).Text;
    string Note = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Controls[0]).Text;

    UpdateRecord(ID, CName, AName, APhone, AEmail, Note); // GridView1.EditIndex = -1; BindGridView();
}
```

**UpdateRecord() Method:**

The update method works well, during the run with breakpoints all the parameters get the updated values but it is not shown in the gridview and not updated in DB

```
private void UpdateOrAddNewRecord(string ID, string CName, string AName, string APhone, string AEmail, string Note)    
{
    OleDbConnection connection = null;
    string conStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\arjun.giridhar\Desktop\db1.mdb;Persist Security Info=False";

    string sqlStatement = "UPDATE Carriers" + " SET CarrierName = @CarrierName, AccountRepName = @AccountRepName, AccountRepContactPhone = @AccountRepContactPhone, AccountRepEmail= @AccountRepEmail, Notes=@Notes" + " WHERE CarrierID = @CarrierID";

    try
    {
        connection = new OleDbConnection(conStr);

        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlStatement, connection);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarrierID", ID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarrierName", CName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountRepName", AName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountRepContactPhone", APhone);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountRepEmail", AEmail);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", Note);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string msg = "Update Error:";
        msg += ex.Message;
        throw new Exception(msg);

    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

**BindGridView() Method:**

```
private void BindGridView()    
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        string sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM Carriers";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlStatement, connection);
        OleDbDataAdapter sqlDa = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        sqlDa.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
         GridView1.DataSourceID = string.Empty;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
    {
        string msg = "Fetch Error:";
        msg += ex.Message;
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }

}
```

Kindly give me a solution.

Regards,
Arjun

Comment: Please attach your code sample

Comment: attaching code will get you more help BTW have you Called DataBind() method of Gridview(rebind Gridview) after updating.

Comment: protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{string ID = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text; 
 string CName= ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;             string AName = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;             string APhone = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;             string AEmail = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Controls[0]).Text;             string Note = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Controls[0]).Text;

Comment: UpdateOrAddNewRecord(ID, CName, AName, APhone, AEmail, Note); //             GridView1.EditIndex = -1;        
BindGridView();}

Comment: You should edit your message to add it there.. code in this format is unreadable (see help for formatting code).

Comment: you made the question more unclear now by posting the code in comments add it in your question simply click edit link below your question and paste it there. where is your bindgridview() method, is that working fine???you forgot to call the BindGridView(); method in your GridView1_RowUpdating event i think

Comment: I am having the same problem. So far what I have found is that in `((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text` (where .Controls[0] is the label and Controls[1] is the textbox) What happens in my code is that when I do get the text from the textbox, it is the value of the text before I changed it. If anyone has further insight, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gridview not updating value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104161/gridview-not-updating-value)

Answer (score 1):

I found another article here: [Gridview not updating value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104161/gridview-not-updating-value?rq=1) which said that this is caused by binding your grid in the `Page_Load` and not checking for postback.  I changed my `Page_load` to:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGridView();
        }
    }
```

That worked.

Comment: Sorry about the format for the code.  I did try to figure it out but was not successful.