# Gridview not updating value

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I am trying to make my gridview update a SQL record but it is not updating the values.

Here is the aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelling" 
    OnRowDeleting ="GridView1_RowDeleting" 
    onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing"
    onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
    DataKeyNames="RID"
    CssClass="mGrid" 
    PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"  
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">  


      <Columns>           

         <asp:TemplateField Visible="false" HeaderText="RID">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label runat="server" ID="RID" Text='<%#Bind("RID")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Short Description">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label runat="server" ID="short_lbl" Text='<%#Bind("SHORT_DESCRIPTION") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="SHORT_DESCRIPTION" Text='<%#Bind("SHORT_DESCRIPTION") %>' />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="valShort" ControlToValidate="SHORT_DESCRIPTION" ValidationGroup="var1" ErrorMessage="*" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>


              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label runat="server" ID="desc_label" Text='<%#Bind("DESCRIPTION") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="DESCRIPTION" Text='<%#Bind("DESCRIPTION") %>' />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="valLast" ControlToValidate="DESCRIPTION" ValidationGroup="var1" ErrorMessage="*" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>



      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
      <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" Text="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
      <br />
      <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" Text="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />
      <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
      </EditItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>

   </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

And the update function itself.

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   string s = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();           
   Label RID = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("RID") as Label;
   TextBox SHORT_DESCRIPTION = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("SHORT_DESCRIPTION") as TextBox;
   TextBox DESCRIPTION = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("DESCRIPTION") as TextBox;

   String UpdateQuery = string.Format("UPDATE TAXONOMIES SET SHORT_DESCRIPTION='{0}', DESCRIPTION='{1}' WHERE RID = {2}", SHORT_DESCRIPTION.Text, DESCRIPTION.Text, Convert.ToInt32(RID.Text));   

    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    BindGridData(UpdateQuery);

}
```

If I put a breakpoint and look at the value, I can see that is is not the newly typed in value.  I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: what are you getting in the `SHORT_DESCRIPTION.Text, DESCRIPTION.Text and RID.Text`

Comment: I get the original values that came from the database(not the updated ones I typed in and clicked 'submit' for)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is you are binding you `grid` on the `page-load` event.
try binding it in if `(!IsPostBack)`

### Example

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //bind your grid here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow good catch!  You were correct, it was doing it on page load.

Comment: You deserve a medal for your guess!

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="regGroupID" HeaderText="regGroupID" 
                SortExpression="regGroupID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="amountReceived" HeaderText="amountReceived" 
                SortExpression="amountReceived" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="other" HeaderText="other" SortExpression="other" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table]" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Table] SET [regGroupID] = @regGroupID, [amountReceived] = @amountReceived, [other] = @other WHERE [id] = @id">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>

    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="regGroupID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="amountReceived" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="other" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

here I set id as the primary key

table structure is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Eval to Bind.  Eval is read-only so you can't actually update the value.

Comment: Still not updating unfortunately, ive updated the original code.